# covariance of two random variables when one is related to the other

Tags: statistics, random-variables, conditional-expectation, variance, covariance

> Let $X$ be a six sided die and $B$ is a Bernoulli random variable with
> mean $p$. If $B=0$, then $Y=X-1$. If $B=1$, then $Y=X+1$. What is the
> covariance of $X$ and $Y$?

I know $cov(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$ but I don't understand how to compute $E[XY]$ in this case. I tried to use iterated expectations $E[XY] = E[Y E[X \mid Y] ]$ but I can't see where that is going.

I can find the mean, variance of $X$ and $Y$. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Conditioning on $B$ is the way to go

Comment: like $E[XY] = E[ E [XY | B] = E[ Y E[X|B] ]$ ?

Comment: Are $X$ and $B$ independent?

Comment: $X$ and $B$ are independent

Comment: If you notice $Y=X+2B-1$ you can immediately say $$\text{cov}(X,Y)=\text{cov}(X,X)+2\text{cov}(X,B)-\text{cov}(X,1)=V(X)$$

Comment: I am not seeing how $Y = X + 2B -1$. If that's the case, then $Var(Y) = Var(X)$ but $Var(Y) = E[Var(Y\mid B)] + Var(E[Y\mid B] ) $ using law of total variance is definitely not $Var(X)$

Comment: @user770687 Casework: if $B=1$, then $Y=X+2-1=X+1$; if $B=0$, then $Y=X-2+1=X-$. It is not true that "$Y=X+2B-1$ implies $\text{Var}(Y) = \text{Var}(X)$"; remember that $B$ contains randomness as well, and so the second term in the law of total variance will show precisely how much more variance $Y$ has compared to $X$. What $Y=X+2B-1$ *does* show is that $\text{Var}(Y \mid B) = \text{Var}(X)$.

Comment: @user770687 $\mathrm{Var}(X) = \frac{35}{12}$ and $\mathrm{Var}(B) = p(1-p)$ and  $\mathrm{Var}(Y)=\mathrm{Var}(X)+4\mathrm{Var}(B)$

Comment: @angryavian I see how it is derived now, that is very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E[XY] = E[E[XY \mid B]] = p E[XY \mid B=1] + (1-p) E[XY \mid B=0]$$

When $B=1$, you know $Y=X-1$, so $E[XY \mid B=1] = E[X(X-1) \mid B=1]$. If $X$ and $B$ are independent (I guess this needs to be assumed), then this equals $E[X(X-1)]$. The other term $E[XY \mid B=0]$ can be handled similarly.

---

In the end, we'd have $$E[XY]=pE[X(X+1)] + (1-p)E[X(X-1)] = E[X^2] - (1-2p) E[X]$$ and $E[Y] = E[E[Y \mid B]] = pE[X+1] + (1-p)E[X-1] = E[X] - (1-2p)$
and thus
$$\text{Cov}(X,Y) = E[X^2] - (1-2p)E[X] - E[X](E[X] -( 1-2p)) = \text{Var}(X)$$
as Matthew Pilling obtained with his much slicker approach.

Comment: Is $E(X(X-1))$ your final answer for $\text{cov}(X,Y)$?

Comment: @MatthewPilling No, I was just explaining how to compute $E[XY \mid B=1]$. The other term would need to be handled similarly.

Comment: Okay, gotcha. And thanks for the shout out! ;)